# Swan SDW2011B dishwasher water inlet error

Tags: dishwasher

I've just bought a second hand Swan SDW2011B dishwasher. After connecting it to the water mains I decided to try it and run an empty washing cycle.
When turned on I can hear the water outlet pump running, followed by the water inlet pump letting water in. It then starts the washing cycle itself, and I can hear water coming out from both rotating arms (also, if I open the door during this stage I can definitively see water inside the machine). It continues for a couple of minute, then the water drains out, the inlet pump starts running again but there's no water coming in. After that, the start/pause LED flashes; according to the manual, that means there's no water coming in.

I am baffled at how this is happening, since the inlet pump does work fine for the first water in cycle. I've obviously checked the water inlet hose and filter and they're all clear; after all, at some point the is water running through them.
Any ideas of what it could be?

Comment: Try a second test cycle. If it fills at the beginning again, but not after a drain, you could have a water valve not opening completely when it is energized for the second time. If it won't fill the first time, then the valve is most likely the issue.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, but unfortunately I had to ged rid of it and buy a new one. I was lucky the guy who sold it was honest and gave me my money back.